# Can't create SQL Statement - Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Well writing a login checker for a game, and switching from C# to java. Problem is I am using older code as an exmaple but keep running into this problem with creating a statement from connection. I get "createStatement() symbol not found". Is there a new way to do SQL statements or is there something else wrong?

Here is the source code.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLCheck {

    public Connection con;
    public void connect(){
        String host = "somewhereoutthere";
        String username = "stuff";
        String pass = "haclmolg";
        String db = "users";

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+"/"+db+"?";
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,username,pass);
            System.out.println("Server: Connected to MYSQL");
        } catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Server: SQL EXECEPTION: " + e.toString());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cE){
            System.out.println("Server: Class not found: " + cE.toString());
        }
    }
    boolean checkLogin(String userName, String password){
        boolean correct = false;

        Statement s = con.createStatement();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, if this ever gets more than a handful of users, please consider converting to OpenID, or at least using a secure protocol to authenticate users.

Comment: Okay all fixed. Actually both answers helped. It was me forgetting "throws SQLException"

Comment: From what I read from the users of OpenID you'd probably want to stay away from it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not reuse the name `Connection` for your own class. When you are declaring objects of type `Connection`, you aren't using the SQL one, you're using your own.

So, when you declare the variable `con`, you're declaring a `tanksgrid.Connection`, not a `java.sql.Connection`. The same for the cast. And when you call `con.createStatement()`, the class `Connection` that you wrote has no such method.

**EDIT:**

With the source update, there is still a lingering problem with the code: you will need to catch an `SQLException` possibly thrown by `createStatement()`. (Also, the method needs to return a boolean value.) Eclipse doesn't see any other problems with the source.

Comment: Even after creating a new class, it still shows "con.createStatement() cannot be found"

Comment: Yes, perhaps renaming the class "TGConnection" or something along those lines?

Comment: Can you update the source code in the original post, then? This problem is definitely present in your original code.

Comment: Yeah I did rename it too, new file and everything. Update Source up above.

Comment: @Seandidk: check my updated answer and see if that helps. I checked in Eclipse, so if the compiler still thinks that `createStatement()` isn't a symbol, you might have other problems (like an out-of-date compilation error, or something - it does sometimes happen in Eclipse).

Answer (score 2):

Naming conflict. The compiler thinks `con` refers to your own `Connection` class.

Either change the name of your class from Connection to MyConnection or something like that OR reference the con object as  `java.sql.Connection con;` If you do this, also change the type cast from `(Connection)` to `(java.sql.Connection)`

Comment: +1: noting that you can use the fully qualified name (`java.sql.Connection`).

Comment: Still nothing. There is a better compile error this time though. "init:
Deleting: C:\Users\Seand\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TanksGrid\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Seand\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TanksGrid\build\built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Seand\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TanksGrid\build\classes
C:\Users\Seand\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TanksGrid\src\tanksgrid\SQLCheck.java:36: unreported exception java.sql.SQLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
1 error
"

Comment: Okay it was me just failing to add "throws SQLException"